# How to avoid constantly calling api?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

How to avoid constantly calling API? I want to avoid that so that the API won't be stressed when calling

```
useEffect(
  React.useCallback(  () => {
    const task = InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions( async () => {
      const _token =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token');
      let UserId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@UserID')
      setToken(_token);
      fetchParents(UserId, _token);
      fetchStudent(UserId, _token);
      fetchTeacher(UserId, _token);
      UserProfile(UserId, _token)
    });
    return () => task.cancel();
  }, [])
); 


const fetchParents = async (UserId, _token) => {
  try {
    fetch(config.API_URL + '/Parents/Application/Access/10/'+UserId, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        //Headers
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ _token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then((response) =>  response.json().then(data=>({status:response.status, body:data})) )
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.status==200)
      {
        if(response.body.length > 0)
        {
          setParent(response.body[0].udf_Users_IsHaveApplicationAccess)
        }else{
          console.log("err");
        }
      }else{
        console.log("error");
      } 
    });
  
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
const fetchStudent = async (UserId, _token) => {
    .....//same code in fetchParents
}
const fetchTeacher = async (UserId, _token) => {
    .....//same code in fetchParents
}
const UserProfile = async (UserId, _token) => {
    .....//same code in fetchParents
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `useCallabck` hook in the wrong way, this hook doesn't need the return statement to cleanup. more information on React's [useCallabck](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) documentation.

First, try to remove the `return` statement from `useCallback`. Then try to implement the callback outside of your `useEffect`:

```
const [task, setTask] = useState(null); // initialize with proper data or leave it blank

const fetchData = React.useCallback(  () => {
    const newTask = InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions( async () => {
      const _token =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token');
      let UserId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@UserID')
      setToken(_token);
      fetchParents(UserId, _token);
      fetchStudent(UserId, _token);
      fetchTeacher(UserId, _token);
      UserProfile(UserId, _token)
    });
    setTask(newTask)
  }, [])


// now, this useEffect run only once after your component did mount
useEffect( () => {
    fetchData()
    // to cleanup tasks on component will mount
    return () => {
      task.cancel();
      setTask(null)  // to remove task from state
  }, [])
);
```

Also, you can call your APIs with an async function without `useCallback` hook (which I guess you used to ignore the async call in your useEffect)

```
async function fetchData () {
  try {
      const newTask = InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions( async () => {
        const _token =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token');
        let UserId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@UserID')
        setToken(_token);
        fetchParents(UserId, _token);
        fetchStudent(UserId, _token);
        fetchTeacher(UserId, _token);
        UserProfile(UserId, _token)
      });
      setTask(newTask)
  } catch (error) {
   // do somethings with error case
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69533847/react-native-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component hi please check this @novonimo